# Exception occurred during event dispatching:java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, oracle, classcastexception

I've been receiving `ClassCastException` in my code. Objective initially was to convert `Set` to `List` since the `refreshDetailVOTable` method will only get `Set`. The problem could have been in converting `Set` to `List`. `refreshDetailVOTable` might took the wrong `List` that's why I'm receiving `ClassCastException`. Any thoughts on this?

```
public List deleteChildPromotionComponentDetails(ClientContext context, List detailIRsToDelete,
    String emergencyAccessPermission) throws RetekBusinessException {

    List exclusionList = null;
    RpmEvent deleteEvent = buildPromotionComponentDetailsDeleteEvent(emergencyAccessPermission);
    deleteEvent.setTransitionNotificationExceptionFlag(true);
    Set detailBOsToDelete = new HashSet();

    for (Iterator iDetails = detailIRsToDelete.iterator(); iDetails.hasNext();) {
         IdentifiableReference detailIR = (IdentifiableReference) iDetails.next();

         PromotionComponentDetail promotionComponentDetail = (PromotionComponentDetail) getService()
                         .readForUpdate(detailIR);
         Set exclusionSet = promotionComponentDetail.getExceptionsAndExclusions();

         exclusionList = new ArrayList (exclusionSet);

         for(Iterator exclusion = exclusionSet.iterator(); exclusion.hasNext();){
             PromotionComponentDetail exclusionDel = (PromotionComponentDetail) exclusion.next();
             exclusionDel.accept(deleteEvent);
             detailBOsToDelete.add(promotionComponentDetail);
         }

     }
     return exclusionList;
}
```

---

```
public void deleteChildDetails(final List parentComponentDetails)
{
    List list = null;
    try {
        list = getCmlPromotionComponentDetailAppService().deleteChildPromotionComponentDetails(
        ClientContext.getInstance(), parentComponentDetails,
        emergencyPermission.getName());
    } catch (RetekBusinessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    refreshDetailVOTable(list);
}
```

Comment: Post a stacktrace of your error.

Comment: You're using all raw types. Use generics instead. They will help you find this kind of error at compile time.

Comment: i will try that, currently im doing research on generics stuffs. would you have any idea or sample what to place on my code for it to compile? thank you @StuartMarks

Comment: Too much for a comment; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the generics tutorial here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

You're doing pretty simple stuff, so you only need to look at the first part. You probably don't need to dive into wildcards.

A guess as to what's happening: your method is receiving a parameter `List detailIRsToDelete` from which you get an iterator and iterate over the elements like so:

```
for (Iterator iDetails = detailIRsToDelete.iterator(); iDetails.hasNext();) {
    IdentifiableReference detailIR = (IdentifiableReference) iDetails.next();
    ...
}
```

If whoever calls you had accidentally put something other than an `IdentifiableReference` into `detailIRsToDelete`, you'd get a `ClassCastException` in the assignment statement within the loop. If instead the list parameter were declared

```
List<IdentifiableReference> detailIRsToDelete
```

the act of putting things into this list would be checked by the compiler, and the error would occur at the point where the erroneous object was added, at compile time, instead of later at runtime, as you're experiencing.

Comment: Thanks @StuartMarks. However I'm receiving a syntax error which says parameter types are only available if source level is 1.5. We are currently using 1.4. Do we have any workaround?

Comment: Wow, 1.4. Nope, can't use generics in 1.4. I was going to suggest using the "checked" collection wrappers (see `Collections.checkedList(list, type)` in order to do checking at runtime, to catch the error when an element of the wrong type is put into the collection. Unfortunately the checked wrappers were also added in 1.5. Maybe this is an incentive for your project to upgrade: enhanced language and library features in newer releases would help prevent bugs like this.